# why multiple files not post: laravel 5.4

Tags: jquery, html, forms, laravel

In my project i want to post some information with multiple images.. All the data has been posted except **Files data** ..i got only **text input values** not **file value** so help me out what i am doing wrong why the images can't be posted??

```html
<form action="{{url('/createAlbum')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {{  csrf_field() }}
  <div class="row album-info">
     <div class="col-md-12 album-txt">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Untitle Album" required>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 album-txt">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="albumLocation" id="album-loc" placeholder="Where were these taken?" required>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
   <div id="content">
      <input type="file" name="album[]" id="filer_input2" multiple="multiple" value="test">
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

**Controller method:**

```
 public function createalbum(Request $request){
 dd($request->all());

}
```

**Find JS files:**

[Custom-Filer.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwoDWemidKeAOWtfSGNHdjViWHM)

[Jquery.filer.min.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwoDWemidKeAVmhrNnF6VTk0VkE)

Comment: that is ok! the file is there...you need to save it!

Comment: @Jamal Ahmad could you please check using this $files = Input::file('album');

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia null result

Comment: @JamalAhmad, I have tested Your code and it is working fine all files will received correct. could you please check you have used use Illuminate\Http\Request; Dependency?

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia yeah i get it.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files can be accessed like this:

`$request->allFiles();`

To get a single file:

`$request->file('key');`

Comment: by this it give a null array

Comment: @JamalAhmad Check your image file size and the max uploads allowed by your php install.